# PHP: d3.js script does not display anything

Tags: php, jquery, html, d3.js

**Problem**: I've got the following code, that runs fine as a standalone .html file. Now, I wish to display this within a .php file. Inside the .php file, I've copy-pasted the same code.

There are some header/footer and other html in the main page where this .php file is to be displayed. However, when I run it But other than the line, "Testing", the chart does not display.

What additional changes should be done ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<div>
      <h4>Testing</h4>
</div>

    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.4.5"></script> -->
    <script src="d3.v3.js"></script>

    <!-- Source for example located at: http://bl.ocks.org/1203641 -->

    <style type="text/css">
        .slice text {
            font-size: 16pt;
            font-family: Arial;
        }   
    </style>

    <script>

    var canvasWidth = 500, //width
      canvasHeight = 700,   //height
      outerRadius = 200,   //radius
      color = d3.scale.category20(); //builtin range of colors

    var dataSet = [
      {"legendLabel":"Your child's Percentile", "magnitude":90}, 
      {"legendLabel":"Ahead of your child", "magnitude":10},
//      {"legendLabel":"Three", "magnitude":50}, 
//      {"legendLabel":"Four", "magnitude":16}, 
//      {"legendLabel":"Five", "magnitude":50}, 
//      {"legendLabel":"Six", "magnitude":8}, 
//      {"legendLabel":"Seven", "magnitude":30}
];

    var vis = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg:svg") //create the SVG element inside the <body>
        .data([dataSet]) //associate our data with the document
        .attr("width", canvasWidth) //set the width of the canvas
        .attr("height", canvasHeight) //set the height of the canvas
        .append("svg:g") //make a group to hold our pie chart
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + 1.5*outerRadius + "," + 1.5*outerRadius + ")") // relocate center of pie to 'outerRadius,outerRadius'

    // This will create <path> elements for us using arc data...
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .outerRadius(outerRadius);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie() //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
      .value(function(d) { return d.magnitude; }) // Binding each value to the pie
      .sort( function(d) { return null; } );

    // Select all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
    var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
      // Associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle,
      // endAngle and value properties) 
      .data(pie)
      // This will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated
      // with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
      .enter()
      // Create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text>
      // element associated with each slice)
      .append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "slice");    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)

    arcs.append("svg:path")
      //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } )
      //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
      .attr("d", arc);

    // Add a legendLabel to each arc slice...
    arcs.append("svg:text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
        //we have to make sure to set these before calling arc.centroid
        d.outerRadius = outerRadius + 50; // Set Outer Coordinate
        d.innerRadius = outerRadius + 45; // Set Inner Coordinate
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle") //center the text on it's origin
      .style("fill", "Purple")
      .style("font", "bold 12px Arial")
      .text(function(d, i) { return dataSet[i].legendLabel; }); //get the label from our original data array

    // Add a magnitude value to the larger arcs, translated to the arc centroid and rotated.
    arcs.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; }).append("svg:text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
        //we have to make sure to set these before calling arc.centroid
        d.outerRadius = outerRadius; // Set Outer Coordinate
        d.innerRadius = outerRadius/2; // Set Inner Coordinate
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
      })
      .style("fill", "White")
      .style("font", "bold 12px Arial")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.magnitude; });

    // Computes the angle of an arc, converting from radians to degrees.
    function angle(d) {
      var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
      return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
    }


                  </script>
            </meta>
      </head>
</html>
```

Comment: sidenote: why is there a closing `</meta>` tag on you markup? they are void tags, and as such they do not need one

Comment: Hi Ghost. I was trying <div> tags before reverting back to this, and so it must've crept in. I removed it, but I get the same result. I checked, all tags are balanced.

Comment: by the way, [it works fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/onoWOB), maybe some wrong path/missing file on your js

Comment: Yeah, it runs fine as a standalone .html file, but not as a .php file. Also, the d3.v3.js file was downloaded as is and is placed in the same folder as this .php file.

Comment: Please can you show us your PHP file?

Comment: Rob, this itself is the .php file. I merely copy-pasted the contents of the properly running .html file, and created a .php out of it . Its invoked from a controller.

Comment: But you said *"There are some header/footer and other html in the main page where this .php file is to be displayed."* ?!

Comment: OK I'm sorry i did not phrase it properly. This code is invoked from a PHP application. This .php is included within a 'larger' page.

The complete html source code is too huge to post here.

Comment: In which case that may well be the problem.  Are you saying that it doesn't work on it's own or only when included on the `parent` page?

Comment: Rob, "only when its included on the parent page." I got an answer by Victor below, sort of.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. The only difference is that I replaced your script tags with remote ones

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

If you are including this file from another PHP file, delete doctype, html, body and head tags - they can't be duplicate in generated file.

**update**: by the way, div tags don't belong to head section

Comment: Victor, that worked (though the html is all garbled, but will take care of that).

But why didn't it work with my script tags ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing parent file. But as I said, the file as posted above is not very good for including (better from including from it since it has html and head tags opening and closing)